# How to map tapped event for a single object in a canvas control in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, foreach

I am working on a windows phone RT XAML c# project. I have a canvas filled with several dynamically added balls(ellipse) as ContentControl. I want that, when a ball is tapped, only that
particular ball should animate. I have used storyboard animation in the animating function animateBall() and the animation function works fine. But, I am not able to map the tapped
event of a single contentcontrol to the animating function animateBall().
I used foreach loop, but it is applying the animation to all the balls.

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="playArea" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="624" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ball" Canvas.Left="167" Canvas.Top="482" Height="105" Tapped="ball_Tapped">
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFE81B1B" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </Canvas>
```

c#

```
bool tapped;
foreach (UIElement ball in playArea.Children)
            {
                ball.Tapped += ball_Tapped;
                double top= Canvas.GetTop(ball);
                if (tapped)
                {
                    animateBall(ball, top, playArea.ActualHeight, "(Canvas.Top)");
                }

            }

void ball_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tapped = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

```
       foreach (UIElement ball in playArea.Children)
       {
           if(ball is ContentControl)
                ball.Tapped += ball_Tapped;    
       }
    }

    void ball_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl ball = sender as ContentControl;
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(ball);
        animateBall(ball, top, playArea.ActualHeight, "(Canvas.Top)");
    }
```

Comment: Thank You so much! It simply worked just the way I wanted.